# 3-4-5 Rule How to partition the sets?

Tags: data-mining, discrete-data, binning

In Data Mining course, we are taking 3-4-5 Rule to segments the data uniformly.

I'm trying to understand these lines below, and how they are linked to the graph below too.

> If an interval covers 3, 6, 7 or 9 distinct values at the most significant digit, partition the range into 3 equi-width intervals
>
> If it covers 2, 4, or 8 distinct values at the most significant digit, partition the range into 4 intervals
>
> If it covers 1, 5, or 10 distinct values at the most significant digit, partition the range into 5 intervals

Why did we partitioned step 3 into 3 intervals and  step 4 to 4 intervals?

The graph:
[image: 3-4-5 Rule Example]

Would really appreciate it if someone could help explaining my question above.

Comment: See this for understanding intuitive partitioning. https://idevji.com/intuitive-partitioning-data-3-4-5-rule/